# I want to create a category just to show products in a particular attribute

Tags: magento, static, attributes, block

Hope you can help Magento users,

I have a clothing store selling big mens clothing. One of my best categories in my old store was allowing the customer to view all the products in his size in one feed. Whilst I am aware they can choose the top level category (menswear) and use the attributes down the left side to select their own size, I would like to have a specific category for instance (All 3xl products) all ready setup in the mega menu. So far I have been able to set a category up and set a url rewrite to the required url attribute. Works fine but I can not add text at the top of the page (for seo purposes). 
I was considering if it is possible to create a static block with only 3xl products in, then I can design the page around the static block?

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon category structure if you are using anchor categories you could create a link directly to an attribute filter.

i.e

I have an attribute called material 
and the value of polycarbonate id is "4"
you can append the values of layered navigation/anchor categories to the end of the url
mysite.com/vehicles.html?material=4

Say for example,  you have an attribute of "size", with the id of 3xl = "10"
and mens was your anchor category.  It would look like 
yoursite.com/mens.html?size=10

Then you would just create a simple html link to http://yoursite.com/mens.html?size=10